# passing an additional parameter to javascript callback for Phonegap File Handling

Tags: javascript, cordova, callback

I am using the PhoneGap API to handle files. I am doing the following call which calls the appendfile function as a callback method.

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", { create: true }, appendFile , onError);
```

this calls :

```
function appendFile(f) {

    f.createWriter(function (writerOb) {
        writerOb.onwrite = function () {
            logit("Done writing to file.<p/>");
        }
        //go to the end of the file...
        writerOb.seek(writerOb.length);
        writerOb.write("Test at " + new Date().toString() + "\n");
    })

}
```

I would like to change the called function to accept an addiitonal parameter of the text I want to append to the file, e.g. :

function appendFile(f, textToWrite) {}

However I cant seem to get this to work. If I change the callback to include the additional parameter I get an error.

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", { create: true }, appendFile(textToWrite) , onError); // doesnt work.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction for this please .... thanks.

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", { create: true }, appendFile , onError);
var textToWrite = 'blah blah';

function appendFile(f) {

    f.createWriter(function (writerOb) {
        writerOb.onwrite = function () {
            logit("Done writing to file.<p/>");
        }
        //go to the end of the file...
        writerOb.seek(writerOb.length);
        writerOb.write("Test at " + new Date().toString() + " " + textToWrite + "\n");
    })

}
```

You can also add properties to function, so

```
appendFile.textToWrite = 'blah blah';
```

then

```
writerOb.write("Test at " + new Date().toString() + " " + appendFile.textToWrite + "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I will mark as answered if no one else can come up with a better solution. This solution is getting around the problem by nesting the function within the code so the textToWrite variable is then "in scope". This should work however I was hoping to understand how additional parameters can be passed to callback functions, maybe this is just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this.

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", { create: true },
 function (f,textToWrite){
 f.createWriter(function (writerOb) {
        writerOb.onwrite = function () {
            logit("Done writing to file.<p/>");
        }
        //go to the end of the file...
        writerOb.seek(writerOb.length);
        writerOb.write("Test at " + new Date().toString() + "\n");
    })
} 
, onError);
```

Note: I couldn't test the code because I don't have the environment

Comment: this doesnt work. textToWrite is "undefined" even when it is defined in the line previous to the above, i.e. :
 
var textToWrite = "Test at " + new Date().toString() + "\n";